# Excel VBA Recordset SQL - No value given for required parameters

Tags: sql, excel, vba, recordset

Whilst the title of this question is similar to other questions asked in the past, I could not via limited searching on Google or SE find an answer that helped me with my problem below.

I am trying to pick up data from an excel sheet for processing. After finding that a more complex SQL statement with a join gave an error, I looked deeper and found the following;

The below SQL statement runs fine:

`SELECT [DNSHEET$].[DNS] FROM [DNSHEET$]`

However the below SQL statement does not & this gives the error stated in title later.

`SELECT [DNSHEET$].[DNK] FROM [DNSHEET$]`

I use the code below for running either SQL statement - they are saved in `sql1` which is defined as a string.

`rs.execute(sql1), cn`

Where `rs` is the Recordset and `cn` the connection.

`cn` is defined as:

`Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn 
.provider="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0"
.ConnectionString="Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _ "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
.open
End with`

`DNS` and `DNK` headers are correctly named and match headers on `DNSHEET` sheet.

`DNS` is populated with string data, `DNK` contains integers from 1 to circa 25000.

**Update**: This issue has been worked around by closing and reopening the excel workbook. Then both of the SQL queries could run.

Hence another question is why this arises and how to find out what the cause of the problem is?

Comment: Honestly this is one of those things were we could waste time trying to figure out why and still not get any answers. The only thing I can think of is schema changes in the workbook causing the sql to break.

Comment: Probably the sheet was updated and was not saved to the persistent storage which is referenced in the connection string. Just a guess, it happens for example when EXCEL worksheet has references to the other book. References look invalid till save.

Comment: So will we need to save after every change to get it to work?

Comment: Also is this a sign of a bug in Excel or by design?